# Running (win) OS entirely in memory

Tags: hard-drive, memory

I have a new comp with 128GB memory and on my older computer I've been using a ram drive for the temp files and various things to avoid trashing the HD's and to speed up things.

Now that I have 128GB I'm wondering if I could dedicate 16 or 32GB to the main OS files and commonly used stuff(and maybe profile to see what is used to optimize). I tend to use my computer for long periods of time between reboots so the initial cost to copy the files is not a big deal.

But is there any way to easily "hot swap" the data? Ideally I'd like to create a ram drive before windows loads, do the copying, and have it load from ram. One could do this back in win3.1 because they had a simple way to create a ram drive before windows loaded.

Is it possible now? I've read I can use grub to make a ram disk. So as long as this is compatible with windows then it is feasible.

I'll need a way to copy the changes after shutdown. I don't care too much about powerloss(battery backup solves that).

Ideally this is what I'd be after:

1. Create ram drive before OS boot
2. Copy OS and commonly used data files to ram drive. (ideally profiled regularly to find out what is most used.
3. Stitch the HD files not copied in to the ramdrive(e.g., using symbolic links)
4. Copy ramdrive back to HD. Ideally by monitoring changes and just copying changes to avoid unnecessary work. Probably do this regularly just to avoid that one time when everything crashes.

This solves a lot of problems with the only real problem caused by a loss of power.

It prolongs HD life. It runs the system cooler as the HD's are not spinning as much. It's faster. While SSD's are fast they still have longevity issues and since an OS is constantly writing small files all the time it's quite inefficient.

Ideally the OS would handle all this seamlessly and learn too use a ramdrive to copy the most read files. Maybe us AI to optimize it all.

My guess though is that what some genius will tell me is that it's a waste of time...

If Grub or similar can get me the ram drive before windows starts and to be able to copy files before windows starts then I could probably automate the rest more or less. I already basically do this but I'm using post boot ram-drive creation and it is only for some files that speed up loading by about 100x(instant versus minutes).

Comment: “While SSD's are fast they still have longevity issues”—they do not. Not using a SSD is making the PC slower on purpose. Use a SSD. // The OS already does what you want. It’s called cache. Of course, it is only populated on demand, so the first access will be slower.

Comment: @KodfkDleepd Everything has a determined longevity, but what we are saying is that SSDs are endurant enough to be used as system disks for years. In any case you don't have to aggressive toward people who take time to answer you.

Comment: There are a few things I find interesting here. First, on a pragmatic level, for the average computer user an SSD is entirely the right choice for what you're proposing. Second, taking your assertions charitably, you are expecting kernel coders here. There may be some, but you're castigating and protesting the answers of anyone giving what you consider to be less than perfect solutions. If you know the answer already, then post it. We're perfectly ok with that here. I suggest not charging those who are taking time to share their knowledge and experience with being ignorant.

Comment: Perhaps you are expecting more high level theoretical information than is what is the norm here.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't know if what you want to do is possible or not.

But anyway even if possible I see little gain -if any- to expect.

The main reason is that all modern OS have a feature that does what you essentially want: the RAM cache. Once read, a file content stays in RAM, as long as there is enough space. At the point there is not enough space left, the OS has to remove some cached content from the RAM, and it uses clever algorithms to do that, based on how frequently the content is accessed. With this mechanism you don't have the certainty that all the OS file are in RAM, but all the OS files don't need to be in RAM, as some of them are rarely used.

The conclusion : let the RAM cache do the work for you.

About SSDs, they are nowadays endurant enough (and actually have been for a long time) to be used as system disks. And this is precisely because *"OS is constantly writing small files"* that they are particularly suited for this usage: SSDs are infinitely more performant than HDDs for random accesses. Using a HHD as a system disk today is like running a marathon with a backpack full of stones... It can do if you have a lot of RAM, thanks to the cache, but RAM is much more expensive than SSDs.

Comment: You expect little gain but this is not true. I already use an ad-hoc solution and as I said, it is 1000x. Literally instant. I have programs that have to read databases and it takes about 2 minutes to load the database when the program starts. If I put the file on a ramdrive it literally loads "instantly"(within about 1 or 2 seconds). You can say that it's not cashed initially and that is true, but then I'm pre-caching it and one can't specify that with the OS caching. I do run on an SSD and I specifically creating this caching to make things faster.

Comment: It can be 1000x faster, yes, once the file is in the RAM. But at first it has to be loaded in the RAM, exactly like when caching it. Now databases access are a special case, as they are highly random and may defeat the cache strategies (although with 128GB I wouldn't worry that much). Maybe putting them on the RAM disk can help, but then the disk can be created after the boot... Note that your question was not about databases but about "the main OS files", which is not the same at all.

Comment: Plus, once again, SSDs are the real solution to your problem. Buy one, put on it the OS and the files for which you need fast access, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - you can indeed allocate part of your RAM as a memory disk,
but you will lose all contents after a shutdown.

This means that you cannot have a persistent RAM disk that you may boot from.

You cannot even copy the operating system to the RAM disk, since many
of its folders are protected and you can't recreate them with all
their attributes.

Comment: Note that the OP addressed the non-pertinency issue in his description: *"4. Copy ramdrive back to HD."*. Their description doesn't assume that the OS would be permanently in RAM.

Comment: @PierU - This answer still is correct. What the author wants to do is not possible with Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not possible with Windows indeed, but the reason is not the non-persistency of the RAM per se.

Comment: @PierU - I disagree with the description that the reason what the author wants to do is not possible is because the drive is not persistent. I would argue, that is a huge part of the reason.

Comment: @Ramhound The non-persistency could be mitigated in several ways: synchronising the files between the ramdisk and the hdd, having only the read-only files on the ramdisk...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Linux - on boot you have option `toram` - then particular Linux copies all media to RAM and boots there. There is no persistence however, so after reset or shutdown all data is lost.

With Windows the case is complicated, as Windows is proprietary and you may need to put much work to put it into RAM and run from there. This is widely possible, but very complex and would need much engineering knowledge to do that. You would need to change some files in Windows at the assembly/binary level to make it work.

The other option which is closer is WindowsToGo, which resides on pendrive nearly as image and is run in a closer manner than Windows residing od disk.

Comment: Linux likely has the ability and I might start trying to use linux again(or have a dual boot). Surely one can have pre-boot and post-shutdown scripts that can do the setup? In windows I have access to scripts that launch in the middle of the boot process and and on "exit" and that allows me to cache many of the non-os files. It would be better just to do it all in one go though and maybe have more of an intelligent system at work(e.g., one that monitors changes and tries to keep things in sync too some degree). toram would solve the first part.

Comment: @KodfkDleepd - Those scripts run long after Windows requires system files to already be on the system drive. You won't be able to create a RAM drive before those files are required.

Comment: @KodfkDleepd - I feel confident and comfortable enough with my knowledge to say what you want isn’t possible, but if you find sharing that opinion as unfriendly and as offensive, I won’t continue to engage with someone that feels like that.

Comment: @KodfkDleepd if the "toram" option does for the first part, then you just have to separate the data from the OS in two different partitions. The OS partition would be loaded to RAM and booted from, and you would have your data on the normal disk: you could then have post-boot scripts that create another ramdisk and copy your data to and from the ramdis when needed. All modified OS settings during the session would be lost, but when needing to modify them you could perform a normal boot.